# Random BSOD on a laptop, even on fresh install. Possible Storage issue

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bsod, storage

Few months ago I started getting random BSOD errors on my Acer Triton 500. It’s a three years old machine which I constantly use. There is no stable scenario when BSOD will happen, so it’s hard to reproduce the issue by my will. All stress tests, long gaming sessions or video rendering complete without any issue. BSOD I've seen:

UNEXPECTED STORE EXCEPTION

SYSTEM SERVICE EXCEPTION

KERNEL DATA INPAGE ERROR

CRITICAL PROCESS DIED

I’ve started thinking it’s some OS issue and decided to reinstall the OS, especially taking into account that Laptop has two SSD’s in RAID 0 and maybe this confuses recent builds of OS. I’ve disabled RAID and now I've got two 256 GB SSD in my laptop. On fresh OS and there was no BSOD for some time (or maybe i wasn’t doing stuff that forces it), but they returned without any obvious reason, now it’s only one error every time:

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR

I caught it 4 times over the past three days and every time it happened when I was moving files. Moving files between two SSD, moving files from external HDD to my laptop. So for now I think it has to do smth with my storage. But still no stable way to reproduce the issue. Let me explain:

I was copying 100500 files from SSD 2 to SSD 1, and caught BSOD. After reboot I tried again and it completed the task without the issue.

I've tried Victoria test utility and caught BSOD after it finished its work, but never got BSOD if I ran it later.

Important notice, the system can’t do a memory dump, it’s just a BSOD screen with 0% all the time.

I’m uploading SMART values from both SSD and Victoria test results. Everything looks normal.

My first goal is to understand the source of this issue. Maybe it’s not an SSD but some controller that handles the copy process? Maybe there is a test utility that can load this part of my computer?

Or maybe my SSD is dying without SMART being able to catch it?

Acer Predator Triton 500 (PT515-51)
Intel Core i7-8750H
Intel Cannon Point HM370, Intel Coffee Lake-H
16Gb, DDR4-2666
2x WDC PC SN720 SDAPNTW-256G-1014  (256 ГБ, PCI-E 3.0 x4)

[image: SSD 1 SMART]

[image: SSD 2 SMART]

[image: SSD 1 Victoria]

[image: SSD 2 Victoria]

Comment: Run memtest86.exe (make a bootable USB with Rufus) and test memory. Get the drive manufacturer's test app and test the drive.

Comment: Manufacturer app shows that the SSD is okay. Memtest is running right now and after three passes it says it’s alright with the memory

Comment: WHEA errors are normally hardware or driver. Could be a motherboard error.  Also update all your drivers and BIOS